# Android NDK : Compiling different libraries for different architectures

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile, java-native-interface

I have a small c++ library that must be compiled for both armeabi and armeabi7a.  I also have a very large c++ library that only needs to be compiled for armeabi.  Right now they are being compiled (using NDK) for both architectures, but this is making my .apk very big.  Is it possible to target the big library to be compiled only for armeabi?  How would I do this?

My folder structure is something like this:

```
/jni/biglib/
/jni/smalllib/
/jni/Application.mk
/jni/Android.mk
```

My /jni/Application.mk file contains:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a armeabi
APP_OPTIM := release
```

My root /jni/Android.mk file combines the Android.mk files for each library:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDE := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

include $(addprefix $(LOCAL_PATH)/, $(addsuffix /Android.mk, \
    biglib \
    smalllib \
))
```

Comment: Can you hack your small library such that `armeabi` version works reasonably well when executed on `armeabi7a` device?

Comment: I don't think so ... it's a 3rd party library and it says in the docs that it must be compiled separately for armeabi7a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is definitely possible. There are some code snippets to get you going (without exact content of Android.mk for biglib and smallib I can't help you more).

1) Change order of `APP_ABI` to `APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a` in `Application.mk`.

2) Modify your root `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDE := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

# biglib is not built for armeabi-v7a
ifneq "$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)" "armeabi-v7a"
  include $(LOCAL_PATH)/biglib/Android.mk
endif

# ----- cut here -----
# Place this snippet to every module which needs biglib, or where convenient.
# Now you will link against armeabi version of biglib.
ifeq "$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)" "armeabi-v7a"
  LOCAL_LDFLAGS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../obj/local/armeabi/libbigLib.so
endif
# ----- cut here -----

include $(LOCAL_PATH)/smalllib/Android.mk
```

And thats all - your `apk` file now doesn't contain `libbiglib.so` for armeabi-v7a

Comment: This worked for compilation, but it is now crashing in runtime on armeabi-v7 phones since Android is looking for libbiglib.so in the armeabi-v7a folder and not finding it.  Is there a way to get it to default to the armeabi version on v7 phones?  I'm getting: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load biglib: findLibrary returned null at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)

Comment: @slamnjam: does the log say which library it cannot find, and in which directory? Do you have two `system.load()` statements in the static constructor?

Comment: @AlexCohn Yes, each library is being used by a different class where the relevant library is loaded in the static constructor.  In fact, I checked on the device and the big library was not even installed in the libs folder on the device.  I created a new question to address this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366009/android-ndk-use-same-library-across-different-abi-architectures