# Android NDK: Use same library across different ABI architectures

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

This is a followup question to : [Android NDK : Compiling different libraries for different architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358130/android-ndk-compiling-different-libraries-for-different-architectures)

My issue is I have two c++ JNI libraries compiled with NDK.  One is small and architecture dependent, and the other is a big library which is the same across architectures.  In order to make the .apk smaller, I would rather have only one copy of the big library.  I tried a folder structure like this:

```
lib/armeabi/libbig.so
lib/armeabi/libsmall.so
lib/armeabi-v7a/libsmall.so
```

However, when I ran it on a v7 device, I got an UnsatisfiedLinkError.  When I checked in the libs folder on the device, only libsmall.so was installed.  My question is: is it possible to have some libraries architecture-independent while others are architecture-dependent.  Something like this:

```
lib/armeabi/libsmall.so
lib/armeabi-v7a/libsmall.so
lib/all/libbig.so
```

Comment: Which device was that? There is a known bug with loader on v. 4.0.whatever loader. Also, if you drop the armeabi-v7a variant altogether, does the app load?

Comment: @AlexCohn  I tried it on a Samsung Galaxy S with v2.3.3 and Samsung S3 with 4.1.2 and it failed on both.  If I drop the armeabi-v7a variant it seems to work fine -- the reason I'm building it for armeabi-v7a is that it is a 3rd-party library and the docs say to build it for both.

Comment: I understand your motivation, even though I think that non-v7a devices are essentially dead by now. I wonder, isn't this caused by ABI incompatibility between `armeabi-v7a/libsmall.so` and `armeabi/libbig.so`? The easy way to check would be as follows: copy `libbig.so` from `obj/local/armeabi` to `obj/local/armeabi-v7a`, and build the APK for **armeabi-v7a** only. Does your app start? Also, you can simply check what libs are installed: `adb ls -l /data/data/whatever.your.app.package.is/lib/`

Comment: @AlexCohn  Yes, I did check the lib folder on the device and the libbig.so library is not installed.  The problem is that when the armeabi-v7a folder is not there, then it falls back to the armeabi folder and installs libbig.so from there.  But when the armeabi-v7a folder IS there, it only installs the libraries in the armeabi-v7a folder and ignores the armeabi folder altogether.  Maybe this is just how Android does it and there is no workaround.  I didn't know pre-v7 was almost dead though -- in that case, maybe I'll compile for v7 only and block the app for non-v7 devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that if v7a boost is so important, then you can simply drop support for non-v7 devices. There is also the option to build and upload separate APKs for different ABIs: https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html.

Finally, you can rearrange the libraries as follows:

```
lib/armeabi/libbig.so           --> lib/armeabi/libbig.so
lib/armeabi/libsmall.so         --> lib/armeabi/libsmall.so
lib/armeabi-v7a/libsmall.so     --> lib/armeabi/libsmall-v7a.so
```

This way, your Java app should choose **"small"** or **"small-v7a"** for [System.loadLibrary()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String%29).